# Issues with bindings inside nested directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

A little background information to help you understand the problem:
We're using angularjs and we've run into a problem regarding how we handle translating  of our sentences to foreign languages. Our current setup looks like this:

JS-Directive:

```
Rohan.directive('translate', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    var translateElement = function(element, data, lang){
        var results = $filter('I')(element.html(), data, lang);

        element.html(results.text);
        if (results.tooltip) element.attr('data-tooltip', results.tooltip);
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                translateElement(element, attrs.translate, scope.currentLanguage);
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

JS-Filter:

```
Rohan.filter('I', [function () {
    return  function (key, data) {
        key = $.trim(key);

        var string = "..." + key + "...";

        try {
            string = Langfile[currentLanguage][key].value;
        } catch (e) {
            console.warn("Translation not found: " + JSON.stringify(key));
        }

        return {"text": string};
};
```

This basically just does a lookup in an array for the correct translation.
So the problem we're facing is when this data-translate tag is nested inside other directives like so:

JS-Problem Directive

```
Rohan.directive('easydialog', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
        scope: {
            text: '@',
            showDialog: '=',
            useableButtons: '=',
            onDialogClicked: '='},
        replace: true,
        template:
                '<div>' +
                '<easymodal data-show="showDialog" title="confirm" data-close-function data-dismissable="false" data-modalbig="false">' +
                    '<button data-ng-repeat="useableButton in useableButtons" data-ng-click="closeWindow(); onDialogClicked(\'{{useableButton}}\')" data-translate>{{useableButton}}</button>' +
                '</easymodal>' +
            '</div>'
    };
});
```

Output:

```
<button>incorrect_input</button>
```

instead of

```
<button>Your input is incorrect</button> //Or whatever language is selected
```

So this results in Angular resolving the data-translate tag first, but at that exact moment {{useableButton}} is still {{useableButton}} and not the value we are actually inserting at that time.

This could be resolved by using that filter but we would actually like to get rid of it as it forces  us to do different workarounds.

So what I'd like to see is:

1. Start processing the Easydialog directive.
2. Change {{useableButton}} to whatever is inside it.
3. Then start the data-translate step on whatever is inside that {{useableButton}}.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that by adding a watch on useablebutton, check for undefined value and when it is set compile your button and add it to your element.

```
Rohan.directive('easydialog', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
        scope: {
            text: '@',
            showDialog: '=',
            useableButtons: '=',
            onDialogClicked: '='},
        replace: true,
        template:
                '<div>' +
                '<easymodal data-show="showDialog" title="confirm" data-close-function data-dismissable="false" data-modalbig="false">' +
                '</easymodal>' +
            '</div>'
        link: function(scope,element,attrs) {
            scope.$watch('useablebutton',function() {
                 if (scope.useableButton) {
                      var button = $compile('<button data-ng-repeat="useableButton in useableButtons" data-ng-click="closeWindow(); onDialogClicked(\'{{useableButton}}\')" data-translate>{{useableButton}}</button>')(scope);
                      element.find('easymodal').append(button);
                 }
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna checkout angular-translate - http://pascalprecht.github.io/angular-translate

Answer (score -1):

One solution could be to use the `I` filter directly inside your directive template, like this:

```
        ...
        template:
            '<div>' +
            '<easymodal data-show="showDialog" title="confirm" data-close-function data-dismissable="false" data-modalbig="false">' +
                '<button data-ng-repeat="useableButton in useableButtons" data-ng-click="closeWindow(); onDialogClicked(\'{{useableButton}}\')">{{useableButton | I}}</button>' +
            '</easymodal>' +
        '</div>'
```

How about modifying your directive to use $interpolate like this:

```
Rohan.directive('translate', ['$filter', '$interpolate', function ($filter, $interpolate) {
   var translateElement = function(element, data, scope){
       var value = $interpolate(element.html())(scope);
       var results = $filter('I')(value, data, scope.currentLanguage);

        element.html(results.text);
        if (results.tooltip) element.attr('data-tooltip', results.tooltip);
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                translateElement(element, attrs.translate, scope);
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: It may have not been clear with this sentence: 'This could be resolved by using that filter but we would actually like to get rid of it as it forces us to do different workarounds.', But i do not want to use that filter! It constricts us with other functionality. regarding triggering the directive again in case of changing language.

Comment: @Rohan Ah, sorry, I clearly didn't pay enough attention! Does it make any difference if you set "priority: 9000" (or something like that) in your translate directive?

Comment: I have actually tried that, priotizing the translate directive causes the directive to recieve an undefined instead of {{useableButton}}. The otherway around causes the problem i am having now.

Comment: And it's not just because the filter is missing the "currentLanguage" parameter in your code? Or maybe that's just a typo here?

Comment: The "currentLanguage" is a javascript global variable, i've simplified the code a bit to hide 'unnecessary' details.

Comment: Ok. I've provided a solution using the $interpolate service now, see my modified answer..

Comment: $interpolate doesn't seem to work, i'm guessing it's because buttons are built up by ng-repeat and $interpolate has no knowledge about that.

Comment: Maybe you get the wrong scope in the link function? usableButton property should be set on the scope, but maybe you get the parent scope where usableButtons is defined instead?